# Can one jsp be used to update the source code of another jsp?

Tags: jsp, admin, updates

Is it possible to change the source code of one jsp using a different jsp?

I was trying to have something where a user with an admin role could use an area and submit button in A.jsp that would display a portion of source code from B.jsp. This user could then change that displayed source code in A.jsp (specifically the respective responses within the logic that displays to a regular user on B.jsp), submit, and have it update the source code of B.jsp, which is inaccessible to the admin as B.jsp is a login error page.

Thanks for any insight,
David

At this point I was just looking as session-based or other possible options. Not even sure if it would work, since a displayed jsp is already conpiled.

Comment: ...I haven't touched JSP in... uh... 18 years. From what I recall aren't *.jsp` pages always compiled to Java `.class` files and _then_ deployed as binaries, so there's no runtime-editable views/templates being deployed into production, unlike with PHP/`.asp`/`.aspx`/`.cshtml` - right?

Comment: Yeah. That's sort of what I was thinking. Similar functionality exists in the project but it uses a database. The error page was a bit of a different animal. Thanks for the feedback. I appreciate it.

Comment: I think the answer is yes. You could  change the source code of one JSP using a different JSP.  The Servlet container(Tomcat) monitors JSP and will recompile them when a change is detected.

Comment: I did some testing. It works. But, whitespace and formatting require  more attention than I gave it in my crude test.  I can't post code because some people think that scriptlets are evil. You can use  Files.writeString(Paths.get(application.getRealPath("editable.jsp")), c);  and  String code = new String(Files.readString(Paths.get(application.getRealPath("editable.jsp"))));